# How to add Notifications

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I am searching for the Option where i can Show the messages in the Menu. e.g. below.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an item that will hold your numeric value, compute it, and substitute it in the label of the menu item surrounded with square brackets

```
Assignees [&F_ASSIGNEE_CNT.]
```

Comment: And if you see something you like in a sample application, you can inspect the code to see how they did it.